# How to remove current Class that is running

Tags: list, class, dispose

Good day! I don't know if my title is right. please change if not :D

Anyway, I do have 3 Rectangles added to `List<Rectangle>` and load it up
given them a class that has event **[ Paint / MouseDown / MouseUp / Mousemove ]** each of them.

Now, the 3 Rectangle that has class are now currently running.

Now, when I removed 1 Rectangle in `List<Rectangle>`
and load it up again, the removed Rectangle still running.

How can I dispose class or classes that are currently running?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

found a solution.

```
    public EventHandlerList DetachEvents(Component obj)
    {
        object objNew = obj.GetType().GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { });
        PropertyInfo propEvents = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        EventHandlerList eventHandlerList_obj = (EventHandlerList)propEvents.GetValue(obj, null);
        EventHandlerList eventHandlerList_objNew = (EventHandlerList)propEvents.GetValue(objNew, null);

        eventHandlerList_objNew.AddHandlers(eventHandlerList_obj);
        eventHandlerList_obj.Dispose();

        return eventHandlerList_objNew;
    }
```

Comment: from this link.

stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control